# Updated 16.04 does not work after login - how can I recover?

Tags: updates, virtualbox, 15.10, 16.04, guest-os

16.04 (now updated from 15.10, under Win7/VirtualBox 5.0.18 as a guest) starts, login appears, then nothing can be seen but the bare desktop background picture only.

Can I recover somehow, or return to 15.10 ?

Comment: Try to get into a terminal (by pressing Ctrl+Alt+F1) and type `mv ~/.config/dconf/user ~/.config/dconf/user.backup`, then try to log in again. Also try `rm .Xauthority`.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem upgrading 14.04 to 16.04 on my desktop machine (hardware), but had the foresight to make a duplicate of the 14.04 partition before upgrading, so I was able to copy the duplicate back, fix the UUID entries in GRUB and fstab, and get back to the same setup I had before upgrading.

If you don't have a backup of the old OS (an image of the complete partition is best) there's no way I know to revert from a non-working upgraded install to an older version.  The old file versions are overwritten or deleted during the upgrade process.

Answer (score -1):

I tried following commands. It worked for me.
After login, press ctrl+alt+F1/F2.
You get terminal window.
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade.

Please try this.